# Controller internal function won't update $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a function inside a $scope which updates a variable inside the $scope - my problem is that the variable is being "restored" to its original value once the function ends:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
$scope.changeWeek = function (direction) {
    console.log(direction);
    console.log($scope.firstdayofweek);
    var d = new Date();
    direction == '7' ? d.setDate($scope.firstdayofweek.getDate() + 7) : d.setDate($scope.firstdayofweek.getDate() - 7);
    $scope.firstdayofweek = d;
    console.log(d);
    console.log($scope.firstdayofweek);
}
$scope.firstdayofweek = getMonday(new Date());
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/TimeSheet/Services/GetSubEmployees.ashx', cache: $templateCache }).
 success(function (data, status) {

     $scope.status = status;
     $scope.fullname = data.fullname;
     $scope.accountname = data.accountname;
     $scope.domain = data.domain;
     $scope.subemployees = data.subemployees;
     $scope.domain == 'IL' ? $scope.firstdayofweek.setDate($scope.firstdayofweek.getDate() - 1) : $scope.firstdayofweek.setDate($scope.firstdayofweek.getDate());

 }).
error(function (data, status) {
    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

}

The markup:

```html
<div class="row" >
  <div class="span1"><a href="#" ng-click="changeWeek(-7)"></a></div>
  <div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:7" class="span1">
    {{(firstdayofweek.getDate()+$index)+'/'+(firstdayofweek.getMonth()+1)}}
  </div>
  <div class="span1"><a href="#" ng-click="changeWeek(7)"></a></div>
</div>
```

$scope.firstdayofweek is updated as expected inside the function (+-7 days) but {{firstdayofweek}} shows the updated date of "now" everytimg I call the function. (The console shows the right updated date)

I'm guessing the controller is refreshed every time - any way I can stop it from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the markup also

Comment: It very basic:<div class="row" >
    <div  class="span1"><a href="#" ng-click="changeWeek(-7)"><<</a></div>
    <div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:7" class="span1">
        {{(firstdayofweek.getDate()+$index)+'/'+(firstdayofweek.getMonth()+1)}}
    </div>
    <div  class="span1"><a href="#" ng-click="changeWeek(7)">>></a></div>
</div>

Comment: Which `range` filter is that?

Comment: Didn't got your point. I put your code [into this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/ysPuZ/) and tried to mock the missing dependencies, and everything is working fine. Which `{{firstdayofweek}}` is not getting updated?